# Skip a certain folder when using os.walk

Tags: python, os.walk

Here is my code:

```
rootdir_path_without_slash = '/home/winpc/Downloads/Prageeth/backups/Final/node-wen-app'
rootdir_path_with_slash= '/home/winpc/Downloads/Prageeth/backups/Final/node-wen-app/'


dir_src = (rootdir_path_with_slash)
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir_path_without_slash):
    for file in files:
        file_name=os.path.join(subdir, file)
        if file_name.endswith('.html'):
            print file_name
```

Here this code navigate all the sub directories from the given source directory for searching .html file.I need to skip if node modules folder found.Please help me.

Comment: Just give an if condition in the for loop with condition as filename == 'node_modules': pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to put an if condition on the *root directory*, to avoid traversing `node_modules` or any of its descendants. You'll want:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir_path_without_slash):
    if 'node_modules' in subdir:
        continue
    ... # rest of your code
```

Also, `subdir` here is a misnomer, the first argument `os.walk` returns is the root path.